# Can I search hashtags on twitter with wildcards

Tags: search, twitter, twitter-search

I'm hoping to find a way to search for hashtags on twitter that contain the characters 'SF'.  For example, there are tweets that have #LVvsSF (yes I'm a 9er fan!) and I'd like to come up with a search string that would pull this tweet if it has the above hashtag or even #SEAvsSF.

I have tried '%23vsSF' and '#%23vsSF' but neither are working.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Wildcards in Twitter search work only on phrases, inside quotes, with spaces on both sides. For example:

```
"this is the * time today that"
```

[try it...](https://twitter.com/search?q=%22this%20is%20the%20*%20time%20today%20that%22&src=typed_query&f=live)

To the best of my knowledge, it is impossible to search Twitter (web app or API) using wildcards in a sigle word or hashtag.